# Xquery order by- orderby based on particular attribute value

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

XML

```
<dog>
  <cat key="x" value="123"/>
  <cat key="y" value="456"/>
  <cat key="z" value="789"/>
</dog>
<dog>
  <cat key="x" value="321"/>
  <cat key="y" value="654"/>
  <cat key="z" value="987"/>     
</dog>
<dog>
  <cat key="x" value="231"/>
  <cat key="y" value="465"/>
  <cat key="z" value="798"/>     
</dog>
```

I want to order by this xml based on value of attribute '**value**' where attribute **key** ="x".
Using xquery how to achieve.

Comment: Show us what you have tried; or at least explain why you are having difficulty understanding the spec.

Comment: @MichaelKay Should I answer such do-my-homework questions? Maybe I should add only a helpful link, not the actual answer?

Comment: @MikeKaskun it's up to you. I'm not going to join the SO thought police who try to tell contributors what they should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access **'value'** where attribute **'key'** is *"x"* by using [XPath Predicates](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).
For example,

```
for $x in //dog
order by $x/cat[@key="x"]/@value
return $x
```